# Cordova, Angular2 & HTML5 Video

Tags: android, html, cordova, video, angular

I'm trying to get something related to HTML5 videos working using Angular2 inside Cordova.

So far, this is what I achieved:

```
<video autoplay="true" loop="true" preload="auto" controls width=300 height=300 webkit-playsinline>
    <source [src]="video.url" type="video/quicktime">
</video>
```

My video source is loaded from the network, and filled in correctly (the `video` object is correctly filled with a **valid** url (it works on my native ios app).

The only thing I can see displayed is the default poster, I can't play the video.

Did anyone managed to make this work ?

(I am deploying on an Android)

Comment: Have something to do with the source type "video/quicktime"? Maybe try another one.

Comment: I would agree with the above comment. Different OS/Browser combinations need different video formats. Its usually best to include a range of formats for full support.

Comment: Your question really is how to play a HTML5 video in *some* Android browser... hard to say! Which Version of Android are you running this on and which Version of Cordova are you using? This would provide info about the browser engine and thus allow for better answers.

Comment: @Rocca Android is running on 5.x although I need to get everything working with 4.x. Version of Cordova is 5.4.1. I am currently testing what loose11 and SnareChops suggested.

Comment: @loose11 that's what I should do, yeah. If you want to get the rep, just post an answer. Cheers